# how to remove punctuation and stop words using python

Tags: python, stop-words, punctuation

I have a python function that must remove **punctuation** and **stop words** but when i print the result it does't remove it.

where is the error in my function?

code:

```
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from string import punctuation
        ppt = '''...!@#$%^&*(){}[]|._-`/?:;"'\,~12345678876543''' 
    
        def text_process(raw_text):
            '''
            parameters:
            =========
            raw_text: text as input
            functions:
            ==========
            - remove all punctuation
            - remove all stop words
            - return a list of the cleaned text
        
            '''
            #check characters to see if they are in punctuation
            nopunc = [char for char in list(raw_text)if char not in ppt]
          
            # join the characters again to form the string
            nopunc = "".join(nopunc)
            
            #now just remove ant stopwords
            return [word for word in nopunc.lower().split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words("english")]

def_test_twtr_preds["tokens"] = def_test_twtr_preds["processed_TEXT"].apply(text_process)


#get most common words in  dataset
all_words = []
for line in list(def_test_twtr_preds["processed_TEXT"]):
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        all_words.append(word.lower())
print("Most common words:\n{}".format(Counter(all_words).most_common(10)))
```

when i display the result of most common words exist in the dataset is:

```
Most common words:
[('the', 281), ('and', 103), ('words', 81), ('…', 70), ('are', 61), ('word', 57), ('for', 55), ('you', 48), ('this', 40), ('.', 34)]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In your example at least the definition (or import) of stopwords is missing.

Comment: Title *how to remove punctuation and stop words using python and regex* looks partially misleading for me - you do not use regex (`re` module) here.

Comment: my mistake but my question was how to remove it using regex or my function as i showed. i will change the question

Comment: You use `nltk`, why not make use of its built-in function to do that?

Comment: @ipramusinto what you mean  i am using the package and function of the nltk.
`word for word in nopunc.lower().split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words("english")`  i am using the package nltk.corpus for stopwords

where is the error in my function ??

Comment: Try to change your code to remove punctuations, s.t `nopunc = [w for w in a.split() if w.isalpha()]`. Does it work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `raw_text.split()` instead of `a.split()`

Answer (score 2):

Beware that `list('your text')` will result `['y','o','u','r','t','e','x','t']` **not**  `['your', 'text']`.

You can remove punctuation using
`nopunc = [w for w in text_raw.split() if w.isalpha()]`

However the code above will also remove the word `I'm` in `I'm fine`. So if you want to get `['I','m','fine']`, you can use the code below:

```
tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"\w+")
nopunc = tokenizer.tokenize(raw_text)
```